# Create date fields with the default null value facing error incorrect date field in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, date

Create a date field in the XML form

```
field name="nextdate" type="calendar" class="inputbox" filter="safehtml" label="COM_COMDATE_FORM_LBL_COMDATEDETAIL_NEXTDATE" description="COM_COMDATE_FORM_DESC_COMDATEDETAIL_NEXTDATE" hint="COM_COMDATE_FORM_LBL_COMDATEDETAIL_NEXTDATE"
```

and in the SQL create a table with the default value null as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__comdate_details` (
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

`state` TINYINT(1)  NULL  DEFAULT 1,
`ordering` INT(11)  NULL  DEFAULT 0,
`checked_out` INT(11)  UNSIGNED,
`checked_out_time` DATETIME NULL  DEFAULT NULL ,
`created_by` INT(11)  NULL  DEFAULT 0,
`modified_by` INT(11)  NULL  DEFAULT 0,
`name` VARCHAR(255)  NULL  DEFAULT "",
`nextdate` DATE NULL  DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

facing error incorrect date field when trying to save the field without selecting a date in the date field Refer to the image[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link which helped to fix my issue https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/41519